# Locus of vectors of a given rank in the exterior algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannian

The rank of $\alpha\in \bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^n$ is the minimal number of decomposable 2-vectors such that $\alpha$ can be written as a sum of them, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra .
Consider the projectivization $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^n)$: what is the dimension of the locus of classes of vectors of a given rank?

We clearly have the Grassmannian, whose dimension is $2(n-2)$, which is the locus of vectors of rank one.
Moreover, the maximal rank is $k$ if $n=2k$ or $2k+1$. I think the locus of vectors of maximal rank should be an open subset of $\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^n$. How about the other cases? What is the link with the $PGL(n)$-orbits in $\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^n$?

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if the locus of bivectors of rank at most $k$ is precisely the locus satisfying $\alpha^{k+1} = 0$. I seem to recall this is true for $k = 1$. If so it shouldn't be hard to compute the dimension by computing the rank of the Jacobian of $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^{k+1}$.

Comment: Sasha's answer is very clear, but your proposition is interesting, thank you! Your description of the locus of bivectors of rank at most $k$ is true, see the wiki page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V = \mathbb{C}^n$. If $\alpha \in \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2V)$ has rank $k$ (though I would rather say it is $2k$ in this case) then there is a unique vector subspace $U \subset V$ of dimension $2k$ such that $\alpha$ is in the image of $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2U) \to \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2V)$. This shows that the locus of rank-$k$ bivectors is isomorphic to an open subspace of the projective bundle
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{Gr}(2k,V)}(\wedge^2\mathcal{U}),
$$
where $\mathcal{U}$ is the tautological bundle. Its dimension, therefore, is
$$
2k(n-2k) + k(2k-1) - 1.
$$
And indeed, these loci are precisely the orbits of $\mathrm{PGL}(V)$.